# Bash: wildcard in argument expands to a filename

Tags: regex, bash, arguments

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
arguments="some explanation"

if [[ $1 == -f ]]; then
    exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S.%%e" "$2"
elif [[ $1 == -d ]]; then
    exiftool -d %Y-%m "-directory<datetimeoriginal" "$2"
elif [[ $1 == -fd ]]; then
    exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S.%%e" "$2"
    exiftool -d %Y-%m "-directory<datetimeoriginal" "$2"
elif [[ $1 == -p ]]; then
    exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d.%%e" "$2"
else
    echo -e $arguments
fi
set +x
```

If I run `exifrename -f .` it renames all files in the current folder. But let's say I have the following 3 files:

IMAG01234.jpg
IMAG01235.jpg
Ralph at home.jpg

and with them I run `exifrename -f IMAG*. It only renames **one** IMAG file.

When I debug this script, I see this:

```
+ [[ -d == -f ]]
+ [[ -d == -d ]]
+ exiftool -d %Y-%m '-directory<datetimeoriginal' IMAG01235.jpg
```

What can I do make the last line say IMAG* and not IMAG01235?

Comment: The shell expands the wildcard before calling exifrename, so it's getting called with several parameters. Maybe use `"$@"` (with a `shift`) instead of `$2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing IMAG*, then the bash shell does globbing and expands IMAG* to 2 files and passes them as arguments to your script. You need to iterate through all the command line arguments:

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

option="$1"  # this contains -f, -d, or something.
shift 1

for filename in "$@"; do
    ls -al "$filename" # Just an example. But you get the point.
done
```

In your case, you could do the following assuming, that there would be always be one option and followed by list of files.

```
option="$1"
shift 1
for filename in "$@"; do
    if [[ "$option" == '-f' ]]; then
        exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S.%%e" "$filename"
    elif [[ "$option" == '-d' ]]; then
        exiftool -d %Y-%m "-directory<datetimeoriginal" "$filename"
    elif [[ "$option" == '-fd' ]]; then
        exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H,%M,%S.%%e" "$filename"
        exiftool -d %Y-%m "-directory<datetimeoriginal" "$filename"
    elif [[ "$option" == '-p' ]]; then
        exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d.%%e" "$filename"
    else
        echo -e $arguments
    fi
done
```

*Note: If you comfortable with bash scripting, it is more readable to do with case/esac instead of bunch of if/else.*

Comment: that did it!   It works perfectly now